# No such file or directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, shell-script

Running this command on the server:

```
mongorestore -c basic --drop -v --db my_db -u user -p pass dump/basic.bson
```

Works perfectly fine.

But when I put this single line in a script (sh) file:

```
Failed: error scanning filesystem: lstat dump/basic.bson
```

And of course, I intend to put quite a few of such lines in that script file.

I even changed the rights of that dump directory, but to no avail. Probably not related. I have no clue. I am pretty confident someone here has )

Looks like we are running:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:        7.8
Codename:       wheezy
```

In any case, it's a VPS in the Google Cloud.

Comment: Are you running the script from the same directory as when you run the command? `dump/basic.bson` is a relative address, it works if you are in a directory which contains a `dump/basic.bson` file, but if you are running the script from another directory it will tell you that it cannot find the file, which is exactly your error message. Just substitute for `dump/basic.bson` its **absolute** path.

Comment: The answer is yes. And I have tried ./dump/basic.bson as well as the full path! It really beats me

Answer (score 0):

And the riddle comes to an end. After having tried rights, absolute paths, whatever.
 
This was the cause: 
I had created the file in Windows, and the **line endings** were wrong. After having fixed that with notepad++, it works like a charm!